# Couchbase:(Java) Parameterized query on ORDER BY clause not working

Tags: java, couchbase, parameterized

I have a Parameterized query that goes

```
String stmt = "SELECT * FROM bucket ... ORDER BY $sortCategory DESC";
```

Then I go:

```
ParameterizedQuery query = ParameterizedQuery.parameterized(stmt, JsonObject.create().put("sortCategory", "dateUploaded"));
```

It's not sorting properly. I even printed out query.statementParameters() and it's printing my parameters properly. It only worked when I did a hardcode ("ORDER BY dateUploaded DESC"). Not sure why this is the case.

Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 0):

The problem happens because the query gets translated into something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM bucket ... ORDER BY 'date' DESC;
```

Which is probably not making reference to the `date` column but to the 'date' value.

You can try using an index representing the column position instead of specifying the column name.

```
String stmt = "SELECT date, column2, column3 FROM bucket ... ORDER BY $sortCategory DESC";

ParameterizedQuery query = ParameterizedQuery.parameterized(stmt, JsonObject.create().put("sortCategory", 1));
```

Comment: The field being sort is actually named "dateUploaded". Sorry about that. It doesn't matter because I chose other fields to sort and it still wasnt working